# tf.gfile.GFile causes memory leak inside docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, file-io, memory-leaks, bucket

I am using this function to read image data from GCS bucket:

```
def _load_image(path, height, width):
try:
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'rb') as fl:
        image_bytes = fl.read()
        image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8), -1)
        return image.astype(np.float32)

except Exception as e:
    logging.exception('Error processing image %s: %s', path, str(e))
    return
```

It is being called inside a loop that reads an image data and outputs it to a .tfrecord file

```
def _write_tf_records(examples, output_filename):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_filename)
    for example in tqdm(examples):
        try:
            image = _load_image(example['path'], height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
            if image is not None:
                encoded_img_string = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
                feature = {
                    'train/label': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(example['classname'])),
                    'train/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(encoded_img_string))
                }

                tf_example = tf.train.Example(features= tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
                writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
    writer.close()
```

The function works fine while executing on local machine reading images from my GCS bucket. But when I try to run this python script from **inside a docker container**, it starts consuming RAM rapidly and ultimately crashes (possible memory leak).

I eliminated other possible reasons and am pretty sure that the `GFile.read()` is the one causing error.

Suggestions for solving this issue?